# RewriteRule directive meaning in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have 2 .htaccess files in my project. This one is in the project root:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ public/$1    [L] 
 </IfModule>
```

and the second one in my /public inventory with this content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

I want to know what exactly are these 3 lines doing:

```
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    ^(.*)$ public/$1    [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, `^$` is a regex that matches a URL path with exactly zero characters, i.e. the `/` page, and redirects to the implementation found in the `public` folder without any extra parameters. The `[L]` at the end means that this is the last rule to run: if the regex matches, then don't go any further through the `.htaccess`.

In the second line, `^(.*)$` is a regex that matches any number of characters, and redirects to the implementation found in the `public` folder but with that path preserved. (`$1` holds whatever pattern was matched inside the first (and, in this case, only set of parentheses in the regex.) So, `/contact-us`, for example would be sent on to `public/contact-us`.

In the third line, it is taking any URL and passing it in the `url` parameter to the `index.php` file; that is, in the `contact-us` example, `$_GET['url']` would be "contact-us".

Comment: I would just add, if you have the "second line", then you don't need the "first line". In the "third line", the `PT` flag is redundant in `.htaccess`.